# How to install a cocoapod that contains a cocoapod?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods

Thank you for taking time to read this.

The following is a simplified example of what I am trying to accomplish with cocoapods in another project.

I have an iOS swift framework named TestDependencyFramework that is dependent on Alamofire. Alamofire is installed as a Cocoapod and installs correctly. Here is the podfile for reference.

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '13.2'

use_frameworks!

target 'TestDependencyFramework' do
  
  # Pods for TestDependencyFramework
  
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 5.2'
end
```

I can make calls to Alamofire as shown in the code below from TestDependencyFramework without errors and the framework builds correctly.

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

class TestClass {
    
    let test = AF.request("https:/google.com").response { response in
        debugPrint(response)
    }
    
}
```

So far so good!

Now I need to make a Cocoapod out of TestDependencyFramework. I have done this and created the TestDependencyFramework.podspec file with the dependency for Alamofire.  Here is the podspec dependency declaration from within TestDependencyFramework.podspec.

`spec.dependency "Alamofire", "~> 5.2"`

- The podspec passes linting using 'pod spec lint'.

So up to this point everything is working.

However when I install TestDependencyFramework and Alamofire as a Cocoapod into a test Cocoatouch application and try to build the application I get a build error within TestDependencyFramework saying it cannot locate Alamofire. See image:

[image: no such module]

#### This is what I did:

- I created a new Cocoatouch app named TCIAug31
- I created a podfile to install Alamofire and TestDependencyFramework.

This is the podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'TCIAug31' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for TCIAug31
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 5.2'
pod 'TestDependencyFramework', :git => 'https://github.com/xxxxxxxx/testCocoapod.git', :tag => '0.0.1'
end
```

- The Cocoapods installed correctly with no error messages.

But this is where the error occurs. I cannot build the app TCIAug31 as TestDependencyFramework cannot locate Alamofire.

See image:[image: module not found]

So even though I have Alamofire installed correctly as a Cocoapod the TestDependencyFramework framework does not see it.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got this working. They key was to create another private repo for holding the podspec of TestDependencyFramework. After pushing the podspec to the repo and updating my podfile to the new source (the podspec repo) the install worked perfectly.

push using `pod repo push reponame TestDependencyFramework.podspec --allow-warnings`